# lambdify to py function: How to maintain the order of symbols constant

Tags: python, function, sympy, symbolic-math, lambdify

I have some symbolic expressions that I have stored in a text file (because they are too large) to read them later in order to find their numerical estimates. So, after I read those expressions (say `foo_sym`), I convert those expressions into python function as follow:

```
import sympy as sym
foo_fn = sym.lambdify(tuple(foo_sym.free_symbols), foo_sym)
```

Some of the symbolic variables in the expression are arrays, so I setup the vectorized version of the function as:

```
import numpy as np
foo_fn_vec = np.vectorize(foo_fn)
```

Now, I find the numerical estimate of the vectorized function as follow:

```
foo_num = foo_fn_vec(var_1, var_2, var_3, ...., var_12)
```

In above code, the order of symbolic values in `var_1, var_2, var_3, ...., var_12` is consistent with the order of symbols I get through `tuple(foo_sym.free_symbols)`. However, every time I restart python and run the above code, I get a `ValueError: math domain error` because the order of symbolic variables as given by `tuple(foo_sym.free_symbols)` seem to have changed, but the order of values in `foo_fn_vec(var_1, var_2, var_3, ...., var_12)` is unchanged.

Is there a method to hold the order of symbols constant in both steps, i.e. while converting to function in `sym.lambdify((var_1, var_2, var_3, ...., var_12), foo_sym)` and while finding the numerical value of the function as `foo_num = foo_fn_vec(var_1, var_2, var_3, ...., var_12)`?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `sym=tuple(ordered(foo_sym.free_symbols))` the symbols retrieved will always be in the same order. You may then want to use these as `foo_fn_vec(*sym)` and then `sym.lambdify(sym, foo_sym)`.

Comment: Where does `ordered()` come from?

Comment: `from sympy.utilities.iterables import ordered`